# Angular 2 - @types/js-base64/index.d.ts' is not a module

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to decode a base64 string in my Angular 2 TS app.  I have installed js-base64 with npm.  [Base64 Github project](https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64)

```
npm install --save @types/js-base64
```

When I include the module in my app I get the following error

```
app/app.module.ts(15,26): error TS2306: File '<fullpath removed>/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/@types/js-base64/index.d.ts' is not a module.
app/login/authentication.service.ts(4,24): error TS2306: File '<fullpath removed>/src/main/resources/static/node_modules/@types/js-base64/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

system.js.config.js import

```
'@types/js-base64': 'npm:@types/js-base64',
```

app.module.ts import

```
import { Base64 } from '@types/js-base64';
```

I can verify that the file exists with the following content:

```
// Type definitions for js-base64 v2.1.9
// Project: https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64
// Definitions by: Denis Carriere <https://github.com/DenisCarriere>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped

/**
## TODO

add methods:
- [x] encode
- [x] encodeURI
- [x] decode
- [ ] atob
- [ ] btoa
- [ ] fromBase64
- [ ] toBase64
- [ ] utob
- [ ] btou
- [ ] noConflict
 */

declare module 'js-base64' {
    namespace JSBase64 {
        const Base64: Base64Static
        interface Base64Static {
            /**
             * .encode
             * @param {String} string
             * @return {String}
             */
            encode(base64: string): string;

            /**
             * .encodeURI
             * @param {String} string
             * @return {String}
             */
            encodeURI(base64: string): string

            /**
             * .decode
             * @param {String} string
             * @return {String}
             */
            decode(base64: string): string

            /**
             * Library version
             */
            VERSION:string
        }
    }
    export = JSBase64
}
```

Is this file a valid module?  If so, what am I missing?  If not, can someone point me to an example of how to decode a base 64 string in Angular2 TS?  Thanks!

**Edit**

I found two workarounds.

**1.  You can include a vanilla js script in an Angular 2 TS project**

Service/Component:

```
declare var Base64: any;
```

index.html

```
<script src="js/base64.js"></script>
```

If the JS library has a constructor, something like should work:

```
this.base64 = new Base64();
```

**2. A better solution is to use a native TypeScript function found in lib.d.ts**

Component/Service

```
let claims = atob(encodedClaims);
```

This will decode a base64 string.  There are also functions to encode as well.

Good luck!